# Basic analogue clock for the GNOME panel?

Tags: gnome, panel, gnome-panel, clock

Is there any way to get an analogue clock in the panel?

I'm not interested in docks, only the the gnome panel, like recent versions of Mac OS support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default clock does not support an analogue mode. However, I did find this [email](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2008-November/164121.html). It suggests an application called [gpe-clock](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gpe-clock). The application is not the most visually appealing with a dark panel theme, but it does support adding a basic analogue clock to the panel. This is what it looks like:

[image: analogue gpe-clock in Ubuntu panel]

So as you can see, the clock is very basic, but it is analogue. The email says:

> To put the newly installed applet on your panel, you need to right-click 
>   on an empty space on the panel bar and click on "Add to panel...".
>   For the rest, you should have no problems.

However, gpe-clock did not show up in the list of applets for me. I had to go to Applications->Accessories->Alarm clock to add it.

You can set it to analogue mode by clicking on the applet and selecting 'Preferences'. From there, simply select 'Analogue format' and hit 'OK'.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, I have not seen any applet for an analogue clock.  In the era before Gnome 2, I do remember having one.

According to all my searches (forums, freshmeat, gtkapps, etc) the closest solution is a dock (like docky or awn) or cairo-clock.  Unforunately those do not meet the needs you specified.